# Changing child in jQuery does not persist in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var data = "<div><p class='a'>Text</p></div>";
$(data).find(".a").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("b");
})

console.log(data);   //will output: <div><p class='a'>Text</p></div> 
                     //instead of <div><p class='a b'>Text</p></div>
```

I'm iterating over a jQuery object `$(data)` and I'm changing the class of the child `<p />`. However, when I output the data after the change the class `.b` is gone.

Why is that so and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the result of the DOM element creation. The string itself is never modified.

```
var data = "<div><p class='a'>Text</p></div>";

// Create the elements from the markup
var elems = $(data);

// Modify the elements
elems.find(".a").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("b");
});

// Append the elements to the DOM
elems.appendTo("body");
```

---

You can actually shorten your code to:

```
$(data).appendTo("body").find(".a").addClass("b");
```

Comment: My question is a lot simplified. Obviously in my example the each is not needed but in my real life example it is.

Comment: @Horen: Alright, but that's just a side note. Point is that you need to reference the creation of the new DOM elements because jQuery doesn't do string manipulation.

Comment: ...if you wanted to see new markup, grab the first element, and use `.outerHTML`, like: `elems[0].outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

In your case `var data` is a string.

But when you do `$(data)` its converted to a jQuery object and stored in memory. The new class b is added to the jQuery object not to the string `data`

You can try something like this

```
var data = "<div><p class='a'>Text</p></div>";

var $data = ""; // to store the jquery object

$data = $(data); // converts string to jQuery object

$data.find(".a").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("b");   
})

console.log($data.get(0).outerHTML); //<div><p class='a b'>Text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you are not modifying the string `data`

When you say `$(data)` it creates a dom structure from the string and the dom is manipulared there after

Comment: @Horen `$(data)` returns a dom structure whih will be modified

Comment: Well, changing `console.log(data);` to `console.log($(data));` still doesn't show changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
var data = "<div><p class='a'>Text</p></div>";
$(data).find('.a').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("b");
}).appendTo('body'); //replace body with the target container
```

Comment: I don't want to append the data to the body before changing the class.